Java Implementation of if else condition for $addFields and $project mongoDB operator Command failed with error 16412 : 'Invalid $addFields
I cannot figure to multiple fields by using $addFields for if else condition in MongoDB with Java operator. My requirement is to add Mutiple fields based of if else condition. I know how to add multiple fields by using $addFields and $project, but not with if else condition.
Can anyone help me how to implement in Java with MongoDB operators?
Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.
$addFields syntax:
.append(system, new Document()
    .append("$cond", new Document()
        .append("if", new Document()
                .append("$eq", Arrays.asList(
                                "$system",
                                "AA"
                        )
                )
        )
        .append("then",  new Document()
                .append("value.amount", new Document()
                        .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                        "$value.amount",
                                        Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                )
                        )
                )
                .append("value2", new Document()
                        .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                        "$value.amount",
                                        Decimal128.parse("-1.0")
                                )
                        )
                )
                
        )

$project :
new Document()
    .append("$project", new Document()
        .append("_id", 0.0)
        .append("value.amount", 0.0)
        .append(sourceSystem, new Document(
                "$cond", new Document(
                "if", new Document("$eq", "true") )
        )
                .append("then", new Document()
                        .append("original.amount", 0.0)
                        .append("amount.amount", 0.0)
                        

        )

Update
new Document()
        .append("$addFields", new Document()
                .append("RecordID", "$_id")
                .append("Period", samplePeriod)
                .append("Reserve", "$ClosingAmt")
                .append("Identifier", new Document().append("$concat", Arrays.asList("$key","  Balance")))
                .append("Reserve", true)
        ),
// Project with condition
new Document()
    .append("$project", new Document()
        .append("tmp", new Document()
            .append("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                    //if
                    new Document("$eq", Arrays.asList("$system","AA")),
                    
                    //then
                    Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("amount", new Document("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount",-1.0))),
                        Arrays.asList("amount1", new Document("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount1",-1.0)))
                    ),

                    //else
                    Arrays.asList(
                        Arrays.asList("amount2",new Document().append("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount2",-1.0))),
                        Arrays.asList("amount3",new Document().append("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount3",-1.0)))
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
new Document().append("$addFields", new Document().append("tmp2", new Document().append("$arrayToObject", "$tmp"))),
new Document().append("$replaceWith", "$tmp2")


I recommend to use Document.parse("{\field1\": {...}}") (better reading) instead of using Document.append(...). Also, can you add some sample data y expected result? Please, use for sample data (https://mongoplayground.net/) y post the link in your post.

@Valijon Thank you for your response .There is no Document.parse ()method . Sorry I didn't have the sample data . I have already implemented the below code and it is working fine but need add if else conditions .

Document.parse. Can you at least share pseudo-code of several fields wants to add. Or, we should suppose field1, field2, field3

@Valijon new Document().append("$addFields", new Document().append("recordId", "$_id")
if{.append("Amt", new Document().append("amount", new Document().append("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount", Decimal128.parse("-1.0") )) ) ).append("Amt2", new Document() .append("amount", new Document().append("$multiply", Arrays.asList("$amount",Decimal128.parse("-1.0")) )))}

updated a pseudo-code in summary

We can use $arrayToObject operator.
Main idea: We create an array structure of fields we need (operator format), convert it to an object, and reshape the final result.
If you comment pipeline steps (from backwards), you can observe how we reshape documents.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "tmp": {
        $cond: [
          {$eq: ["$system","AA"]},
          [
            [ "amount", { "$multiply": ["$value.amount",2.0]}],
            [ "field1", "$value.field1"],
            [ "field2", "$value.field2"],
            [ "field3", "$value.field3"]
          ],
          [
            [ "amount", { "$multiply": ["$amount.amount",-2.0]}],
            [ "field1", "$amount.field3"],
            [ "field2", "$amount.field2"],
            [ "field3", "$amount.field1"]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: { tmp2: {"$arrayToObject": "$tmp"}}
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$tmp2"
  }
])

MongoPlayground | All in 1 step

Thank you for the solution .I tried the way you suggested but the java service is failing with  'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Expression $cond takes exactly 3 arguments. . Could you please help me

@Rose Share your code please, I can look where the typo is.

here there is a limitation of characters, not sure how can I share the code. But my previous code is available in description.

I have updated my code as a answer .Please check

@Rose Updated your post

@Valinon Sorry to ask ,I just want to know that have you updated the format or provided any solution.Please help me how to add if else conditions for £&addfields and & project.I have tried couple of options but all are giving some issue.Appreciate your help

Not able to add more than 3 fields in the array. It is throwing an error Command failed with error 16020 (Location16020): 'Invalid $project :: caused by :: Expression $cond takes exactly 3 arguments. 4 were passed in.'

                     new Document()
                        .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                .append("RecordID", "$_id")
                                .append("Period", samplePeriod)
                                 .append("Reserve", "$ClosingAmt")
                                .append("Identifier", new Document()
                                        .append("$concat", Arrays.asList(
                                                        "$key",
                                                        "  Balance"
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                                .append("Reserve", true)

                        ),
                //
                new Document()
                        .append("$project", new Document()
                                .append("tmp", new Document()
                                        .append("$cond", Arrays.asList(
                                                        new Document()
                                                                .append("$eq", Arrays.asList(
                                                                                "$system",
                                                                                "AA"
                                                                        )
                                                                ),

                                                                Arrays.asList(
                                                                        "amount",
                                                                        new Document()
                                                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                                                                "$amount",
                                                                                                -1.0
                                                                                        )
                                                                                )
                                                                ),
                                                                Arrays.asList(
                                                                        "amount1",
                                                                        new Document()
                                                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                                                                "$amount1",
                                                                                                -1.0
                                                                                        )
                                                                                )
                                                                ),Arrays.asList(
                                                                        "amount2",
                                                                        new Document()
                                                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                                                                "$amount2",
                                                                                                -1.0
                                                                                        )
                                                                                )
                                                                ),
                                                                Arrays.asList(
                                                                        "amount3",
                                                                        new Document()
                                                                                .append("$multiply", Arrays.asList(
                                                                                                "$amount3",
                                                                                                -1.0
                                                                                        )
                                                                                )
                                                                ),




                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        ),
                new Document()
                        .append("$addFields", new Document()
                                .append("tmp2", new Document()
                                        .append("$arrayToObject", "$tmp")
                                )
                        ),
                new Document()
                        .append("$replaceWith", "$tmp2"),

  


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
